# Setting a datefield a few days back

Tags: django

In my models.py I have two datefields and I want to set the date of one relative to what the user inputs from a form in the other. How do I get the stored value and set it a few days back?

Answer (score 0):

In the `save()` method, add or subtract a [`datetime.timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) from one of them and insert into the other before saving.